# "Bucket name must match the regex" error when using AWS SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

Using aws-sam-cli==0.48.0 I am trying to upload a lambda inside an existing folder of an AWS S3 bucket. The path is "my-modelling/lambdas"

When I execute this command on a MacOS command line:

```
sam package --template-file template.yaml --output-template-file deploy --s3-bucket my-modelling/lambdas
```

I get:

```
Error: Unable to upload artifact module/ referenced by CodeUri parameter of MyFunction resource.
Parameter validation failed:
Invalid bucket name "my-modelling/lambdas": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$" or be an ARN matching the regex "^arn:(aws).*:s3:[a-z\-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}$"
```

Note that **this works fine** if I only specify the bucket name:

```
sam package --template-file template.yaml --output-template-file deploy --s3-bucket my-modelling
```

Can you let me know what the correct syntax is to specify a folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html#bucketnamingrules):

> Bucket names can consist **only** of lowercase letters, numbers, dots (.), and hyphens (-).

Therefore, your bucket name `my-modelling/lambdas` is incorrect since it contains `/`.

To add [prefix](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-package.html) use `--s3-prefix`:

> Prefix added to the artifacts name that are uploaded to the Amazon S3 bucket. The prefix name is a **path name (folder name)** for the Amazon S3 bucket.